# Tenses in literature review / Dead author

Tags: tenses

In the sentence : "In her book Pride & Prejudice, Jane Austen describes/described Mr. Darcy as a proud man."

Which tense is more suitable to be used: simple past/simple present?

p/s: I've research this and got mixed answers.

Comment: You've got mixed answers precisely because both are fine. Which one to pick will depend entirely on context.

Comment: Whichever one you pick, stick with that form throughout the paper/essay/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

> "In her book Pride & Prejudice, Jane Austen describes Mr. Darcy as a
>   proud man."

I think that would be the better option.

Using 'described' wouldn't be wrong but I think 'describes' is better-suited as we're talking about a (classic) novel here and those usually tend to be timeless.

So, in my opinion, simple present would be more apt in the current context. I would venture to say 'described' would probably be more suited if it were a ship's log or a journal or something. My reasoning might be a tad off but I believe the users here would agree.

I'm interested in knowing what others have to say.